# How to copy a directory into another directory, where destination uses an asterisk to complete its name?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

The following command works:

```
cd *foo
```

And the directory is changed to `1234foo`. The numbers before `foo` can variate, and the `foo` part will be always the same.
However, when I'm trying to copy `bar` into `*foo`, it won't work.

```
C:\>copy bar *foo\
bar\*
The system cannot find the file specified.
       0 file(s) copied.
```

I'm aware that this might be a duplicate question.

Comment: Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `for /?` and read the output help. In the command prompt window use `for /D %I in ("*foo") do copy "bar" "%I\"` and in a batch file `for /D %%I in ("*foo") do copy "bar" "%%I\"`. Run in same command prompt window also `cmd /?` to output the usage help of __CMD__ and `copy /?` for the help of [Windows command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) __COPY__.

Answer (score 0):

```
pushd "*foo"
copy bar .
popd
```

Naturally, you'll have to adjust `bar` to suit. `..\bar` would seem appropriate.

Comment: It would be better to use `pushd "*foo" && (copy ..\bar . & popd)` just to make sure to copy the file only on changing the current directory really worked. Well, `copy bar .` does not work on directory not changed, but it also does not work on directory changed as explained by you because of the file is in the parent directory after successful execution of `pushd`. The code should be changed to work at least on successful changing the current directory to a subdirectory of which name ends with `foo`.